# Two $variable as data points in an html button

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm trying to call 2 java value and set them both as data points in this html button, had the code work before, lost it, rookie oversight issue, someone feel nice enough to help me see what i'm missing?

```
<?php $cuid = $user['cuid']?>
<?php $ruid = $user['ruid']?>
<?php echo $cuid; echo $ruid?>
```

[all calls fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxQen.png)

APPLIED:

```
<span class="glf-button" data-glf-cuid="a7898b02-f26c-41e4-8a34-293ec7ab65aa" data-glf-ruid="<?php $ruid = $user['ruid']?>"  > See MENU  Order</span>
<script src="https://www.fbgcdn.com/embedder/js/ewm2.js" defer async ></script>
```

WORKS!!!

```
<span class="glf-button" data-glf-cuid="<?php $cuid = $user['cuid']?>" data-glf-ruid="313438d5-7599-4306-aad9-177ae5cdf317"  > See MENU  Order</span>
<script src="https://www.fbgcdn.com/embedder/js/ewm2.js" defer async ></script>
```

WORKS

```
<span class="glf-button" data-glf-cuid="<?php $cuid = $user['cuid']?>" data-glf-ruid="<?php  $ruid = $user['ruid']?>"  > See MENU  Order</span>
<script src="https://www.fbgcdn.com/embedder/js/ewm2.js" defer async ></script>
```

DOES NOT WORK

Comment: The two snippets you claim work do not work either. That's because you need to `echo` the variables, not just store them in other variables. Just use `data-glf-cuid="<?= $user['cuid'] ?>"` and similar for ruid. (There's also no JavaScript involved here, let alone Java)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need an `echo` to send the value of the array occurance out with the rest of the HTML

```
<span class="glf-button" data-glf-cuid="a7898b02-f26c-41e4-8a34-293ec7ab65aa" data-glf-ruid="<?php echo $user['ruid'];?>">See MENU  Order</span>
```

And of course on the other line as well

Alternatively you could do

```
<?php 
$cuid = $user['cuid'];
$ruid = $user['ruid'];
?>
```

and then later on in the code us `$ruid` and `$cuid` but they would also need echoing

```
<span class="glf-button" data-glf-cuid="a7898b02-f26c-41e4-8a34-293ec7ab65aa" data-glf-ruid="<?php echo $ruid;?>">See MENU  Order</span>
```

unless you use this syntax

```
<span class="glf-button" data-glf-cuid="a7898b02-f26c-41e4-8a34-293ec7ab65aa" data-glf-ruid="<?=$ruid?>">See MENU  Order</span>
```

But why bother using another variable when you already have the data in the array